# Missing \scriptstyle and \scriptscriptstyle letters with libertine and newtxmath

Tags: fonts, math-mode, libertine, newtx

I have manually installed the `newtx` package to `TEXMFLOCAL` (with admin rights), placing everything into the appropriate folders in `TEXMFLOCAL/fonts/` and `TEXMFLOCAL/tex/latex`, and running `updmap-sys --enable Map=ntx.map` and `texhash`. And everything seems to work fine.

However, it seems like I am missing `\scriptstyle` and `\scriptscriptstyle` sized letters in math mode (which is very noticable when I am trying to write fractions, etc.):
[image: Missing scriptstyle sized letters!]

I am only getting g, v, and y!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage[nf]{libertine} % Disable osf in math
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % only encoding that works with Libertine

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[libertine]{newtxmath}
\usepackage[scr=rsfso]{mathalfa} % Differently defined script font
\usepackage{bm} % load after all math to give access to bold math

\begin{document}
Displaystyle:
\[
    abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz
\]

Scriptstyle:
\[
    \scriptstyle{abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz}
\]

Scriptscripystyle:
\[
    \scriptscriptstyle{abcdefghijklmopqrstuvwxyz}
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Trying to contact the author about this; any ideas where I can find "Michael Sharpe"'s email address?

Comment: This looks fixed in the latest release, using TL2012. That suggests this is a now-fixed bug.

Comment: Thanks; I was just thinking about that myself. Can I somehow mark this question as answered/close it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to close this question:
TeXlive 2012 fixes the above problem, and you should just update to it instead of installing `newtx` by hand.